# How to see text in toast

Tags: android, gridview, toast, android-toast

I'm trying to see text from GridView using a toast when I selected or clicked on GridView's data. I can see position, but don't know what to put to see a text.
Here is a code.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String [] data = {"a","b", "c","d","e","f", "g","h"};
    GridView gdView;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    String result;

        @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.item, R.id.tvText, data);

        gdView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gdView);
        gdView.setAdapter(adapter);


        gdView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Could someone suggest me, what I need to use or where to look for it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `int position` of the method `onItemClick()` on `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` gives you:

> The position of the view in the adapter.

See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html#onItemClick(android.widget.AdapterView, android.view.View, int, long)

You can use this to retrieve the content of this view from your `ArrayAdapter` with:

```
adapter.getItem(position)
```

See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int)

This will return the content of your `ArrayAdapter` at the given position, in your case as a `String`, which you can store in a variable if you like or pass directly into `Toast.makeText()`.

Comment: Ci_, I did'nt understand what to do

Comment: You use that instead of just "position" in Toast.makeText().

Comment: Cool!!! It's works, Thank you very much, I knew there must be easy answer. But I still don't understand how it works, but anyway thank you.

Comment: I've edited the answer to give a bit more detail, if you still have trouble understanding it, explain exactly which part of it.

Comment: With your explanation I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Turn last string to

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: `String.valueOf(position)` will only return `the string representation of the given int.` So basically, it won't give you `Text` considered as data of your `TextView` in your list item, but only the position of list item click

Comment: As I understand, the problem is that he passes integer into makeText, and Android resolves it like a resourse ID. So If he wants to see a text, he should wrap it. Question is a little bit unclear

Comment: @Kaerdan. You are right, I want to see a text which is in `String [] data = {"a","b", "c","d","e","f", "g","h"};`.

When I clicking **a** `toast` shows **a**, and so on...